# Lua inheritance override function

Tags: inheritance, lua

I'm fairly new to Lua and I am trying to get a class system to work. What I would like to do it to have a base class which has a bunch of properties and then extend this class for objects such as buttons, textboxes, etc.

The base class will have properties such as `x`, `y`, `width`, `height` etc and then the other classes will have, say, `label` or `colour` or similar.

If I create a function such as render() on the base class, and try to override this function later on, it doesn't seem to work. (Presumably I'm using classes completely wrong!)

Here is a reproduction down example of what I am using:

```
Base = {}
Base.__index = Base
function Base.create(value)
    local b = {}
    setmetatable(b, Base)
    b.value = value
    return b
end

function Base:render()
    print("I'm the base! : "..self.value)
end

Button = {}
Button.__index = Base

function Button.create(value)
    local b = Base.create(value)
    setmetatable(b, Button)
    return b
end

function Button:render()
    print("I'm a button! : "..self.value)
end

Button.create("TestBtn"):render()
```

What I would like the `Button.create("TestBtn"):render()` do is to print `I'm a button! : TestBtn` however it prints `I'm the base! : TestBtn`.

Could someone help me to override the original `render` function with this new one?

Thanks, Will.

Comment: `Button.__index = Base` is incorrect. Notice how that's the same as `Base.__index = Base`

Comment: @Etan Okay then. I thought that was how the inheritance did its magic. So, what am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Well, so I think I was a bit abrupt there. That is correct for chaining  `Button` to `Base`. The issue is that you aren't using `Button` itself as `__index` on anything. You need to `setmetatable(b, {__index = Button})` in `Button.create` I believe. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ah, that works now. Wonderful. Thank you very much :) I think I am misunderstanding the use of __index and metatable a bit. I better look that up. If you wanna add your comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct for you.

Comment: No, `Button.__index = Button` actually was correct. This makes the methods defined in the `Button` class available to the objects created in `Button.create` (`Button` is used both as the metatable for button objects and as the table holding the button methods). What was missing is the inheritance link between base class and derived class: `setmetatable(Button, Base)`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing detail, as @siffiejoe mentioned and I hinted at, is that as written your `Button` objects don't know to look in the `Button` table for methods.

My solution created garbage tables to create that association and so isn't really the best solution but illustrated the point.

@siffiejoe's answer is better in that it more accurately codifies the desired functionality and relationship. It also then requires the extra step of chaining the "class" tables (i.e. `setmetatable(Button, Base)`).

The key here is the operation of the `index` metamethod. This is described with code in the lua [Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.8):

```
"index": The indexing access table[key].

function gettable_event (table, key)
   local h
   if type(table) == "table" then
     local v = rawget(table, key)
     if v ~= nil then return v end
     h = metatable(table).__index
     if h == nil then return nil end
   else
     h = metatable(table).__index
     if h == nil then
       error(···)
     end
   end
   if type(h) == "function" then
     return (h(table, key))     -- call the handler
   else return h[key]           -- or repeat operation on it
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Define `Button:render` instead of `Button:test`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That was rather stupid of me! However it still seems to run the Base:render() instead: codepad.org/AfODqE9J